# Robotjs protractor test not working on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, npm, continuous-integration, protractor

I am running a set of protractor tests that run on Jenkins. A couple of my tests use the robotjs npm package. When tested manually the tests perform fine, but when they are run from Jenkins it seems like robotjs does not work at all. Does any one have any experience with robotjs and Jenkins?

Thanks

Comment: You have to be more specific on what you tried and what's the error (maybe add some code too).

Comment: I tried running the tests manually and they all passed. I also use a mysql npm package that works fine on Jenkins and I didn't get an error when Jenkins ran npm update so the package is definitely getting installed. The first test that involves robotjs just employs a simple mouseMove() and it didn't work so it failed there. Is there any other thing I could provide that could help?